# Free Mercator, Vector Maps

Tags: data, vector, cartography, illustrator

Are there any free, vector, mercator projection maps available online? I'm not wanting satellite imagery, but more a stylized map along the lines of this:

[image]

However, I need it to be vector-based such that I can create sharp tiles for greater levels of zoom.

Ideally, I would like an Illustrator file for something resembling the above map.

Comment: I am not sure of anything that comes in a Mercator projection, but have you checked out the NaturalEarth vector datasets? They come in a Geographic Projection (WGS84 datum) but that can be reprojected using a lot of Open Source (free) GIS Software and exported to a Format that AI can read. http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: Very interesting, @SaultDon. I'll look into that.

Comment: I didn't wanna post these as answers, because they relate to Data, and not an actual Map, but there is also the Vector Map Level 0 from NIMA http://www.mapability.com/index1.html?http&&&www.mapability.com/info/vmap0_index.html this dataset can require a little more pre-processing but the Natural Earth Dataset might be preferred as it is 'cartographically' designed.

Comment: Did you look at arcgisonline.com?

Answer (score 1):

Not Mercator but Robinson Projection

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps#World

SVG imported into illustrator (or [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)) can be saved as illustrator format.

Answer (score 1):

With [FlexProjector](http://www.flexprojector.com) from B. Jenny, Institute of Geography at the ETH-Z and T. Patterson, US NPS, you can view and export the projected map in shapefile format.

Answer (score 1):

Can you import SVG?

A modified mercator prj:
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/World_map_(Miller_cylindrical_projection,_blank).svg

These are SVG files with just land outlines:
http://fastsvg.com/maps/maps.html

Answer (score 0):

You can download a little library of free vector maps of different countries in mercator projection from our company [here](http://vectormap.info/?s=free%20mercator).

We also sell vector maps but this set is totally free.

[image]